# Error while creating a controller for a cloud using juju

Tags: openstack, juju

sudo juju bootstrap --constraints tags=juju mymaas maas-controller

Creating Juju controller "maas-controller" on mymaas
Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.3.7 for amd64
Launching controller instance(s) on mymaas...
ERROR failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance: failed to acquire node: unexpected: ServerError: 400 BAD REQUEST ({"tags": ["No such tag(s): 'juju'."]})

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to: https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.5/en/reference-constraints

This is an issue with tagging in MAAS as well as not using supported tags:

tags=juju mymaas maas-controller

This will specifically look for all servers with all of the tags:

- juju
- mymaas
- maas-controller

Unless your maas controller has a server with all of those tags attached to it it will not find any servers and error out saying it cannot acquire a node with those tags, as it did.

Make the constraints match the supported standard, i.e. resource constraints.

Or, use a non-supported feature that I use when I deploy charms to maas and use the hostname.

juju bootstrap --to hostname.superdomain.com

this will search maas (assuming you have set it up correctly) for that hostname specifically and use it to bootstrap.